# Display image with image location in string

Tags: java, android, eclipse, imageview

I am trying to display an image in android. I have made a new layout with a imageview called "**image**". the string in question is "**SelectedImage**=/storage/sdcard0/DCIM/Camera/IMG_20130602_133933.jpg" the code looks something like this:

```
ImageView imageView1 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
    BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    options.inSampleSize = 2;
    Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(SelectedImage, options);
    imageView1.setImageBitmap(bm); 
setContentView(R.layout.image);
```

when I run it it crashes. the log says

```
06-08 21:24:41.192: I/System.out(7642): Not a DRM File, opening notmally
06-08 21:24:41.192: I/System.out(7642): buffer returned 
06-08 21:24:41.232: D/AndroidRuntime(7642): Shutting down VM
06-08 21:24:41.232: W/dalvikvm(7642): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x414c1438)
```

Comment: Do you have the permission in your manifest to access the sd card?

Comment: You should add READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE as a permission. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html#READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have the appropriate permissions set in your manifest and try something like this:

```
// This is the layout file that includes the imageview
setContentView(R.layout.image);

String selectedImage = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/DCIM/Camera/IMG_20130602_133933.jpg";
File f_path = new File(selectedImage);
InputStream fis = new FileInputStream(f_path);

ImageView imageView1 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
options.inSampleSize = 2;
Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeStream (fis, null, options)
imageView1.setImageBitmap(bm);
```

Answer (score 1):

First check if add the permission to the Android manifest file

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```